# Why this transverse wave appear in this function?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, wave-equation

I was teaching a class about waves, working with a few examples on desmos i decided to try it out some different functions, so i did
$$f(x) = a\cos(kx+b\sin(\omega x))$$

I noticed that in some specific values of $\omega$ it is possible to notice a transverse wave in the graph, that the "thickness" of this wave in some sense can be controlled by the "b" constant.   I could not explain why this behavior emerges.

[image: transverse wave inside transverse wave]

For some $k$ values you also get these interesting cylindrical patterns:

[image]

why?

Comment: Really beautiful. Is this specific of some values of $\omega$? What happens generically?

Comment: It's called "frequency modulation" (FM) : see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation  , especially the section on Sinusoidal baseband signal.

Comment: In general there are some values that the wave looks like the textbook definition of an FM wave and then this transverse wave appears and starts inversely proportional to $\omega$ and then becomes proportional to it. I could post a video animation here but not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: I'm familiar with FM waves, my question is how to make sense mathematically of this transverse wave that appears inside. Not only that, as b rises the function start to look like sea waves reflecting on the "borders" (the amplitude value of the base wave)

Answer (score 1):

Some partial progress was achieved on that behalf.

Firstly, I started to model the behavior of function graphs embedded on 3d space
as a parametric curve and got to the following parametrization:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the graph of a bounded function with $f_1 = \max (|f(t)|)$, this is the function you want to embed in a 3d parametric curve. Let it be guided by two other parametric equations $g,h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$.

A possible parametrization can be given by:

$p(t) = \frac{(1-\frac{f(t)}{f_1})}{2}g(t) + \frac{(1+\frac{f(t)}{f1})}{2}h(t)$

This is a generalization of the linear interpolation between the two points in 3d space, parametrized by the graph $f(t)$.
For example, for the case in which we have $f(t) = \sin(\omega t)$, $g(t)=<r_1 \cos(t), r_1 \sin(t), t>$ and $h(t)=<r_2 \cos(t), r_2 \sin(t), t+c>$

We get that $p(t) =<p_{1}(t),p_{2}(t), p_{3}(t)>$ is

$p_{1}(t) = \frac{\cos(t)}{2}(r_1 + r_2 + (r_2 - r_1)\sin(\omega t))$,

$p_{2}(t) = \frac{\sin(t)}{2}(r_1 + r_2 + (r_2 - r_1)\sin(\omega t))$ and

$p_{3}(t) = \frac{c}{2} (1+\sin(\omega t)) + t$.

Which give us the following plot:

[image]

That way I was able to embbed the sinusoid as in a "ribbon" into 3d space. Noticing this setup looked quite reminiscent of the previous plot so I tried to project back the plot as a parametric equation in the XZ plane.

For my surprise the plot of the equation in the question and this parametric projection looked almost a perfect match, except for the orientation of the oscillations, as we can see in the next Figure:

[image]

The plot in orange represents $<p_{3}(t), p_{1}(t)>$ and the plot in blue is the plot from the original question.

This makes me believe I'm somewhat closer to understand the nature of this cylindrical projection in the FM function. Maybe some minor tweaks in the parametrization will allow me to find a function that closely resembles the FM function at those specific values.